# Get url between text

Tags: regex

I wanted to get the url from the below given text

`<a href="/film/3022900-12-years-a-slave" class="item-link">`
The required data is `/film/3022900-12-years-a-slave` just need data after `href="` and between the `"`

I am using

```
"\w+
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the problems you're having.

Comment: Can you provide desired output too, some more information will be helpful

Comment: Generally, there might be issues parsing an anchor and getting the href. However, you could come up with sth. like `href="([^"]+)`. That is, match href=" literally, then match everything up to a doublequote. But please provide additional information (e.g. programming language).

Comment: Doing it in django ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only text and there are no other html then you can use the following regex:

```
href="([^"]+)
```

or may be you can use a `lookbehind` too depending on your situation.

```
(?<=href=")([^"]+)
```

But if it is a part of large html file then you should use any DOM or similar parser (probably).